# How to toggle between 2 iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I've been trying so many different codes but I can't seem to make it work with my iframes. I can't use jquery so I'm looking for a javascript/css answer

I want the user to see map1 as default and on clicking map2, to see map2 and hide map1.

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('map1')" ><b>map1</b></a>               
<a href="javascript:toggle('map2')" ><b>map2</b></a>

<div id="map1">
    <div class="embed-container">
    <iframe class="crime-rate-wards" width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" title="crime" 
    src="http://birkbeck.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=8a4e79b3c8584a75bda00b262d84263f&amp;
    extent=-0.5836,51.3506,0.4252,51.6629&amp;home=true&amp;zoom=true&amp;scale=true&amp;legend=true&amp;disable_scroll=true&amp;theme=light">
    </iframe>
</div>      
</div>
<div id="map2" style="display:none;">
    <div class="embed-container">
    <iframe class="crime-rate-borough" width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" title="crime2" 
    src="http://birkbeck.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=e96ac6e24dc94b919945e7c95be2ee95&amp;
    extent=-0.5836,51.3506,0.4252,51.6629&amp;home=true&amp;zoom=true&amp;legend=true&amp;disable_scroll=true&amp;theme=light">
    </iframe>
</div>  
</div>
```

Here's the jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Luffydude/PPhqQ/36/

Comment: looks like it is working to me according to your fiddle

Comment: that's strange, for me the fiddle isn't working, nor my html page

Comment: Just to confirm @Ronnie - your fiddle works fine for me with Chrome / Win7.

I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code at first reading

Comment: It works for me in chrome/OSX